# Specified shipping method if the cart has some kind of products

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to setup special shipping for some kind of products.
If the cart has some of this product specified shipping method (for this special products) should be available only.

Is it possible without installing non-free modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in standard Magento, you can only set shipping to "free" ( for all shipping methods ) for particular products via cart rules. And yes, it is possible without installing 3rd party modules, if you write this functionality by yourself :P